# Strategy for using Google Cloud BigQuery (...or any node.js client library) with Nuxt 3/Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, nuxt.js

**Context**

I am writing a Nuxt.js application which will fetch data from Google Cloud BigQuery, and I am planning to perform these queries directly from the front-end using a BigQuery client-side library.

**Problem**

Previously I have worked with Firebase Firestore which has client-side libraries that work directly in the browser on the front-end, however, there seems to be no such library for BigQuery. I tried using the [BigQuery NodeJs library](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/latest) instead, but as expected, I got errors as the code was running in Nuxt and not a NodeJs environment.

My question is what the best approach to a situation like this is? Some suggested to use the NodeJs library and import all the missing modules ([link](https://www.thecodingcouple.com/uncaught-typeerror-util-inherits-is-not-a-function/)). Perhaps I must put the BigQuery code on a NodeJs server and fetch using that from the front-end? If so, would it be possible to do this using built-in server directory in Nuxt?

**Update 1**

I set up an api endpoint in the `server/api/` directory in Nuxt where I called the BigQuery NodeJs library from, which worked! Correct me if I am wrong, but I think that is because it is a Nitro server, which is built on NodeJs? I think my strategy will be to write api endpoints for all the BigQuery querying, which I then call from my front-end using simply `useFetch()` in Nuxt.